# "occurrences" vs "recurrences"

Tags: difference, vocabulary

Say a user selects an event in a calendar which is scheduled weekly. I want to give him the option to edit or delete the event only at the selected date, or edit all the events scheduled weekly.

What is the correct way to label the options?

(1)

- Edit only 24th July
- Edit all **occurrences**

(2)

- Edit only 24th July
- Edit all **recurrences**

Answer (score 2):

An occurrence is every instance of the event.
A recurrence is every instance after the first event.

So the first recurrence of the event is the second occurence.

If I understand correctly you want the option to change every event, including the first one. In this case I would say that "Occurrence" is the right way to lable it.